# regex url problem

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, url

i'm using this regex

```
((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

to match urls (found here http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls it's the bottom one) and when i use match in actionscript 3 it returns the link and everything after it, so if I tried this 'hello http://www.apple.com world' it will return 'http://www.apple.com world' how do I JUST get the url and not the 'world' part.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var match = "hello http://www.apple.com world".match(/\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i)
```

as does this:

```
var match = "hello http://www.apple.com world".match(new RegExp(
    "\\b((?:https?://|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)"+
    "(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+"+
    "(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|"+
    "[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))",

    "i" // case insensitive
));
```

Just remember the string quoting rules. If you quote your regexp with `//` like the first example then you need to backslash escape literal `/`. If you quote your regexp with `""` then you need to backslash escape all `"` and `\` because the backsalsh itself has meaning within strings.

Also, remember that the URL is caught in the first capture group which you can access with:

```
if (match) {
    url = match[1];
}
```

or if you supply the global flag `g` then the matches will be an array of all captured URLs.